# How to get an exclusive lock on a file in go

Tags: go

How can I get an exclusive read access to a file in go? I have tried documentations from docs but I am still able to open the file in notepad and edit it. I want to deny any other process to have access to read and write while the first process has not closed it explicitly. In .NET I could do something as:

```
File.Open("a.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

How do I do it in go?

Comment: Such a feature depends on the file system in use and cannot be guaranteed by Go.

Comment: There is no "Microsoft" tag but this question is specifically aimed at using Go on Microsoft operating systems

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I finally found a go package that can lock a file.

Here is the repo:
**https://github.com/juju/fslock**

```
go get -u github.com/juju/fslock
```

this package does exactly what it says

> fslock provides a cross-process mutex based on file locks that works
>   on windows and *nix platforms. fslock relies on LockFileEx on Windows
>   and flock on *nix systems. The timeout feature uses overlapped IO on
>   Windows, but on *nix platforms, timing out requires the use of a
>   goroutine that will run until the lock is acquired, regardless of
>   timeout. If you need to avoid this use of goroutines, poll TryLock in
>   a loop.

To use this package, first, create a new lock for the lockfile

```
func New(filename string) *Lock
```

This API will create the lockfile if it already doesn't exist.

Then we can use the lockhandle to lock (or try lock) the file

```
func (l *Lock) Lock() error
```

There is also a timeout version of the above function that will try to get the lock of the file until timeout

```
func (l *Lock) LockWithTimeout(timeout time.Duration) error
```

Finally, if you are done, release the acquired lock by

```
func (l *Lock) Unlock() error
```

Very basic implementation

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/juju/fslock"
)

func main() {
    lock := fslock.New("../lock.txt")
    lockErr := lock.TryLock()
    if lockErr != nil {
        fmt.Println("falied to acquire lock > " + lockErr.Error())
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("got the lock")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)

    // release the lock
    lock.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21244637)

Comment: Please don't delete this answer. This is written for someone who might need to do this/similar stuff in future. I have spent a lot of hrs to search this package

Comment: your package uses flock() for locking on Unix so doesn't provide OS level mandatory locking

Comment: we were only looking for windows

Comment: this package is GPL licensed, so can't be used for commercial products. Any other package that you have come across?

Comment: @AmitBhaira It is LGPLv3 which allows for use in commercial products.  See https://choosealicense.com/licenses/lgpl-3.0/

Comment: GPL also allows commercial use! It just needs you to distribute the whole program using the GPL code under GPL itself when publishing. With LGPL, you need to publish changes to the library under LGPL (or compatible) again when releasing the program.

Comment: I see this package problematic because there hasn't been any modification to the code since 2016. If the author was Donald Knuth I'd say this is okay but apparently the Go community has some thoughts on it as well: https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/33974-add-public-lockedfile-pkg.md

Comment: @KonradKleine Man you're a life saver. We've been having issues with "github.com/nightlyone/lockfile" and I'm not sure if the library is bugged or I screwed up. It's not clear what guarantees that library makes and the other couple libraries also leave me feeling a little uneasy. Glad the Go team has an official thread on it. :)

Comment: Using LGPL licensed libraries in commercial closed-sourced golang projects doesn't really work, [see here](https://www.makeworld.space/2021/01/lgpl_go.html). There is an alternative to this library that is BSD-3 licensed: https://github.com/gofrs/flock