# Exclusive locking in Go

Tags: go

How can a file be opened such that only one process can write to it at a time in Golang?

I am new to Golang and was trying to learn it by writing something. Was attempting to create a secret storage tool which stores, say, api keys to a file; during which I came across an issue - if two instance of same program runs together (hypothetically) a race condition can occur and damage the file.

So, I was checking for a way to lock the file so that only one process can write to it at a time. Reading simultaneously is ok.

---

Found this answer : [How to get an exclusive lock on a file in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986413/how-to-get-an-exclusive-lock-on-a-file-in-go) on stackoverflow. but in the comments of the same, it's mentioned

> your package uses flock() for locking on Unix so doesn't provide OS level mandatory locking

---

Tried `os.ModeExclusive`.

```golang
f, err := os.OpenFile(".secrets", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModeExclusive)
```

But it prevents the file from accessing the next time program runs. Can you please explain what this mode does. Not able to understand it from the docs.

---

Also tried:

```golang
f, err := os.OpenFile(".secrets", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, 0744)
```

On using the above, anyone can read/write when the file is opened.

---

Comment: "But it prevents the file from accessing the next time program runs." Did you remember to close the file, preferably using a `defer` statement? Also, what platform are you on? Filesystem locking semantics are quite different between different operating systems.

Comment: In any case, locking only prevents one possible way of file corruption. Another is when your program or computer crashes partway through writing the file. A more robust solution (at least on Unix) is to write the data to a temporary file in the same directory first, close it, and then rename it to the final name.

Comment: I am on Windows and yes.. file is defer closed

Comment: ok.. let me they that renaming method.. thank you..

Comment: On Windows your concern about `flock` is unfounded, because `flock` is not used on Windows.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks for that info. Can you please explain what os.ModExclusive does?

Comment: @Tony why not build a pipeline using a channel? You can have a goroutine which reads from a channel and writes to a file. Your other goroutines can just publish to a channel.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain the `os.ModeExclusive` bit of your question:

> Tried `os.ModeExclusive`.
>
> ```
> f, err := os.OpenFile(".secrets", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModeExclusive)
> ```
>
> But it prevents the file from accessing the next time program runs.
> Can you please explain what this mode does. Not able to understand it
> from the docs.

`OpenFile()` with `os.ModeExclusive` basically creates a file where not even the file owner has read and write permissions on it (at least this is the behavior I observed on unix). that is why it "doesn't work" the next time when it tries to open the file again:

```
$ cat prog.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        f, err := os.OpenFile(".secrets", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModeExclusive)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer f.Close()

        fmt.Fprintf(f, "this is my secret\n")
}
$ go build prog.go
$ ./prog
$ ls -al
total 2.1M
drwxr-xr-x 2 marco marco 4.0K Aug 28 13:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 marco marco 4.0K Aug 28 13:22 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 marco marco 2.1M Aug 28 13:53 prog*
-rw-r--r-- 1 marco marco  230 Aug 28 13:49 prog.go
---------- 1 marco marco   17 Aug 28 13:53 .secrets    <-- HERE IT IS
$ ./prog
2021/08/28 13:54:27 open .secrets: permission denied
$ cat .secrets
cat: .secrets: Permission denied
$ chmod u+rw .secrets
$ cat .secrets
this is my secret
$
```

`os.ModeExclusive` can also be used with `Chmod()` of course on already existing files.

Comment: @Tony glad to have helped you :) my answer doesn't fully answer your question though, so I'll totally understand if you want to un-accept it and wait for a more complete answer from other users. maybe leave an upvote :)

Comment: Hei @MarcoLucidi. Thanks. Done as you mentioned. :)

Answer (score 0):

> The convention (at least for the standard library) is the following: No function/method is safe for concurrent use unless explicitly stated (or obvious from the context).
> It is not safe to write concurrently to an os.File via Write() without external synchronization.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30746629/13067552

You can use `RMutex` from `sync` package to avoid data race. `*sync.RWMutex`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sync"
)

type MyFile struct {
    l    *sync.RWMutex
    file *os.File
}

func (f *MyFile) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    f.l.Lock()
    defer f.l.Unlock()

    return f.file.Write(b)
}

func (f *MyFile) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    f.l.RLock()
    defer f.l.RUnlock()

    return f.file.Read(b)
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("tmp")
    if err != nil {
        // handle here
    }
    defer f.Close()

    myfile := &MyFile{
        l:    &sync.RWMutex{},
        file: f,
    }

    myfile.Write([]byte("secret"))

    b1 := make([]byte, 5)
    myfile.Read(b1)

    fmt.Println(string(b1))
}
```

Comment: mutex locks can be used to avoid critical section access within same program; here what is needed is some method to avoid concurrent write to same file by two different processes. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Tony, I got you - sorry misunderstood the question.

Have you tried this pkg:  https://github.com/nightlyone/lockfile